Solution to a quadratically constrained quadratic program with unit ball constraint
I am working on a quadratically constrained quadratic program (QCQP) of the form:$$ \min_{x} \quad \frac{1}{2} x^T P x + q^T x + r$$
$$ \text{subject to} \qquad x^{T}x \leq 1   $$
where $P \in S^{++}_{n}$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix, and $q \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a given vector. I aim to show that the optimal solution $x^{*}$ satisfies:$$ x^{*}=-(P+ \lambda I)^{-1}q$$
where $ \lambda$ =$\max\{ 0,\bar{\lambda}\}$ and $\bar{\lambda}$ is the largest solution to the nonlinear equation:$$q^{T}(P+\lambda I)^{-2}q=1 $$
I tried solving this by using the necessary and sufficient conditions for the optimal solution:$$ x \text{ is optimal if and only if } x \in X \text{ and}
\\
\nabla f_0(x)^T (y - x) \geq 0 \quad \text{for all} \quad y \in X.
$$
But I wasn't able to make progress.Is there an alternative approach to solve this problem, or any hints on how to use the optimality conditions more effectively? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

You may want to read up on Trust Region methods.

$\newcommand\R{\Bbb R}\newcommand\la{\lambda}$Remark 1:

Let
\begin{equation*}
    g(s):=q^T(P+sI)^{-2}q
\end{equation*}
for real $s$ such that $P+sI$ is invertible. The function $g$ is nonnegative and nonincreasing on the interval $I_P:=(-\la_{\min},\infty)$, and $g(\infty-)=0$, where $\la_{\min}>0$ is the smallest eigenvalue of the symmetric positive-definite matrix $P$.
Moreover, the equation
\begin{equation*}
    g(s)=1 \tag{0}\label{0}
\end{equation*}
$s\in I_P$ has at most one root, because (i) if $q\ne0$, then $g'(s)=-2q^T(P+sI)^{-3}q<0$ for all $s\in I_P$ and hence $g$ is strictly decreasing and (ii) if $q=0$, then $g(s)=0$ for all $s\in I_P$ and hence equation \eqref{0} has no roots. So,

if $q\ne0$, then equation \eqref{0} has at most one nonnegative root, and then this root is the largest real root of \eqref{0};

if $q=0$, then equation \eqref{0} has no real roots.



Let now
\begin{equation*}
    f(z):=\frac12\,z^T Pz+q^T z+r
\end{equation*}
for $z\in\R^n$. The function $f$ is strictly convex. So, $f$ attains its minimum on the closed unit ball $B$ at a unique point $x\in B$. As you noted, we have
\begin{equation*}
    0\le\min_{y\in B}a^T(y-x)=-|a|-a^T x, \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    a:=\nabla f(x)=Px+q \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{equation*}
and $|\cdot|$ is the Euclidean norm. Since $x\in B$, we have $-a^T x\le|a|$.
So, by \eqref{1},
\begin{equation*}
 -a^T x=|a|.  \tag{3}\label{3}  
\end{equation*}
So, for
$$t:=|a|,$$
we have one of the following two cases:
Case 1: $t>0$. Then, since $x\in B$, \eqref{3} and \eqref{2} imply $x=-a/|a|=-\frac1t\,(Px+q)$, so that $|x|=1$ and
\begin{equation*}
    x=-(P+tI)^{-1}q, \tag{4}\label{4}
\end{equation*}
whence $g(t)=x^T x=1$ and therefore, by Remark 1, $t>0$ is the largest root $s$ of equation \eqref{0} -- as desired, because, obviously, here $t=\max(0,t)$.
Case 2: $t=0$, that is, $a=0$, that is, $x=-P^{-1}q$ -- so that \eqref{4} still holds. In this case $1\ge x^T x=q^TP^{-2}q$, so that $g(t)=g(0)\le1$. So, in this case, $t$ is a root of \eqref{0} if  and only if $|x|=1$.
So, in view of Remark 1, in this case your claim about the minimizer will hold if and only if $q\ne0$ and $|x|=1$. The latter condition will not of course hold in general even if $q\ne0$: e.g., if $n=1$ and $f(z)=z^2+z$, then $x=-1/2$ and $|x|<1$.
We conclude that, in both cases, \eqref{4} holds for the unique minimizer $x$ of $f$. Moreover, your claim about the minimizer $x$ will hold if and only if $q\ne0$ and $|x|=1$.

These conclusions can also be obtained a bit more elementarily, by first diagonalizing $P$ and using the spherical symmetry of $B$.

Thanks for such an explicit and clear explanation！

In case2, you mean g(s)=1 may have no root. But if s < -$\lambda$ , will g(s)=1 may still have root? On this basis, my claim about the minimizer still holds in general?

@nuobeitang : Good point. I have made the corresponding changes.

I really want to vote your answer.Since I’m new here, I don’t have enough reputation to cast a vote.
